# permanent Windows session on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

i'd like to have a remote PC where i could install Visual Studio & other softwares that it would be **permanent**

all i've tried for now is volatile so i can't reinstall everything every time i want to use the remote PC.

i've searched online but all solutions talked about EBS (Elastic Block Store)
i even went to http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/ but i can't find EBS in the AWS panel...

where can i get EBS? or is there another way to get a permanent Windows on EC2?

thanks

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you launch an EC2 instance you get a root volume (c:) on EBS by default, it would only be transient if you are using instance storage. To check that, verify the "root device type" property of your Windows image (AMI).

Additional EBS or Instance Store volumes can be added in the "Add Storage" section of the launch wizard.

You can also create an image from the existing instance (Actions > Create Image) and then launch it as many times as you'd like.

Additionally, for persistent desktop sessions, check Amazon Workspaces.